# How do I install vim on OSX with Python 3 support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, vim

I have trouble installing `vim` with `python 3` for `MacOS`. I'm aware that there is a similar [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1115159/how-do-i-install-vim-on-osx-with-python-3-support) on that topic. but I couldn't solve the problem

first I ran `vim --version` and got

```
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    -mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
-arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           -mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     -termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      -terminal
+builtin_terms   +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    -keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        -langmap         +printer         +visual
-conceal         +libcall         -profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             -rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
-emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            -mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
-farsi           -mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

which is the default `vim` version installed on my mac. Unfortunately, it says: `-python3`. So I assume python 3 is not installed. So what I did is the following:

`brew remove vim` 
which went ok and then 
`brew info vim`
and got the following message:

```
vim: stable 8.1.1550 (bottled), HEAD
Vi 'workalike' with many additional features
https://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with:
  ex-vi (because vim and ex-vi both install bin/ex and bin/view)
  macvim (because vim and macvim both install vi* binaries)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✔, lua ✔, perl ✔, python ✔, ruby ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 89,945 (30 days), 222,053 (90 days), 835,730 (365 days)
install_on_request: 82,933 (30 days), 204,131 (90 days), 747,520 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Is it because there are 2 versions of `vim` installed now?

I also tried `brew install vim --with-python3` but got the following message
`invalid option: --with-python3`
when typing `vim --version`, I get:

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2019 19:03:04)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

**EDIT**

Here are commands with their corresponding outputs

- `sudo nano /etc/paths`:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

- `command -v vim`:

```
/usr/bin/vim
```

- `$PATH`:

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

Moreover I posted a similar question on [another platform](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362833/make-homebrew-installed-vim-override-system-installed-one/362840?noredirect=1#comment481906_362840) and did many attempt to try solving the problem. However the problem still persists.

Comment: `invalid option: --with-python3`
that's because Python3 is now the default python in Homebrew.

Comment: thanks for the comment @ParthS007. Ok, but why does it say `-python3`?

Comment: On macOS, set `alias python=python3` in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`, then `brew install vim`, and `which vim` should be `/usr/local/bin/vim`, which supports python3. Source: https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2021/09/04/mac-os-en-install-vim-support-python3/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The version of Vim you're running is the built-in Apple version, which you can see in the second line ("Compiled by root@apple.com"). You can install either the `vim` or `macvim` packages with Homebrew and they will have Python 3 built in, since, as ParthS007 mentioned, the default Python is Python 3.

However, your `PATH` environment variable will need to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` if you want to use the Homebrew version over the default system version (which you almost certainly do). You can edit your shell configuration to change the setting and then restart your terminal session.

If your `PATH` environment variable is set correctly, it's possible you may also have to run `brew link vim` (or `brew link macvim`) to create the appropriate symlinks. In general, you'll want `command -v vim` to show `/usr/local/bin/vim`. Running `/usr/local/bin/vim` by hand should show the correct Vim installed.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @bk2204. It appears to be already the case. Here what I get after the command `sudo nano /etc/paths`: `/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`. Moreover I posted a similar question on another platform and did many attempt (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362833/make-homebrew-installed-vim-override-system-installed-one/362840?noredirect=1#comment481906_362840). However the problem still persists. Do you have another idea?

Comment: What do you get when you run `command -v vim` and 'echo $PATH`?

Comment: Many thanks: @bk2204. I edited the question with requested command and corresponding outputs. Do you see where the problem could be?

Comment: I had to add /opt/homebrew/bin to my /etc/paths.  I put it 2nd after /usr/local/bin (Mac M1)

Comment: For me it was `/opt/homebrew/opt/vim/bin/vim`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
./configure \
--with-python3-command=python3
```

Both `--with-python3` and `--with-python3-config-dir` are deprecated.