# Installing Vim with Python3 support?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, vim, homebrew

I installed Vim on my MacBook today (using `brew install vim`), but I am having a problem: `vim --version` tells me that there is no Python 3, which I need. I already reinstalled the newest version of Python from their website, then did `brew delete vim` and `brew cleanup` and reinstalled Vim, but I'm still having the same problem. Online, I saw the option to use the flag `--with-python3` when installing, but when I try that, I get told that this flag doesn't exist. Now I don't know what to do. Do I need to install Python via Homebrew? I also found some people online saying that there are versions of Vim compiled without Python, and that you can compile Vim yourself. Do I need to do that? How?

I should add: I'm very new to this, so if you post your answers or maybe need some more information from me, please explain in detail so I can understand.

Comment: Okay, why do people use this site? To get help with their problems and learn new stuff. Why don't I know how vim and all works? Because I never used it before. Everybody who uses vim had to learn this stuff, didn't they? But you not only didn't help me, you told me to just not use something I can't use yet? Maybe I shouldn't have started working with computers, because at some point I didn't know how they worked?

Comment: Please refer: 1.[How do I install vim on OSX with Python 3 support?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710705/10846570)

Comment: Bro, Never Give Up! I know You will do that Great Job.

Comment: @RalphBear yes you are right when you are saying "Okay, why do people use this site? To get help with their problems and learn new stuff.", but tagging is also important. When you use the tag `python-3.x`, people are expecting to see a programming problem. Anyway, have a good day.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a new too.

First, use brew to remove vim you should input `brew uninstall vim`.Then try to reinstall vim.

For instance, if you wanted to recompile Vim 8 with Python 3 support on Linux, you can try do the following:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
$ cd vim/src
$ ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: And I also use Homebrew install python3 on my Mac. It's default  for vim8 to use Python3 Feature .

Comment: So I recommend reinstall vim by Homebrew firstly, if it don't work, he can try recompile vim8 with github. Also in this way you can just install newer version vim than Homebrew. It's not silly at all.

Comment: `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp --enable-fail-if-missing --with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3 --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu` that what worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Update Dec.11 2023 EST 11:10PM

Make sure to back up your configuration file for Vim editor `".vimrc"`.

Also, thank you `@dandam` for your feedback!

So,

I include this answer to "`Way 0`" and "`Way 1`".

_______________________________________________________________---Way 0 Begin---(:

Way 0:

we should reinstall `python3` and `VIM`,

1.run the below on terminal

```
brew reinstall python3
```

the upstairs shows that we reinstall python3 to make sure that needed by VIM.

2.continue run on terminal

```
brew uninstall vim
```

the upstairs shows that uninstall vim only if you previously installed it

3.run on terminal

```
brew install vim
```

the upstairs shows that reinstall vim via Homebrew

4.run on terminal

4.1 directly use $SHELL command

```
alias vim=/usr/local/bin/vim
```

4.2 or `bash` 's profile(if you use `bash` as `SHELL`)

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/vim/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

4.3 OR `zsh` configuration file(if  you use `zsh` as `SHELL`)

edit your `zsh` configuration file `~/.zshrc` via

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

and add the below to TOP line(just use `i` to enter editing status,

then use "`:wq`" to quit editing status and save file):

```
export VIM_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.2.2100/

export PATH=$PATH:$VIM_HOME/bin
```

and active that config

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

(Both 4.1 or 4.2 or 4.3 are the same function.)

the upstairs 4.1/4.2/4.3 shows that we let shell command `vim` using Homebrew`VIM` not the default`VIM`.

We know the default `VIM` functional file is located at `/usr/bin/vim`,

while homebrew `VIM` functional file is located at `/usr/local/bin/vim`;

And default `VIM` support `Python2` with not supporting `Python3`,

but homebrew `VIM` support `Python3`(That's also we needed!).

Let's look at Homebrew `VIM`:

Homebrew will install `VIM` vim  at `/usr/local/Cellar/vim`,

create soft link `vim` under `/usr/local/opt`,

and Homebrew `VIM` 's functional file `vim` is located at `/usr/local/bin/vim`, also linked to `/usr/local/Cellar/vim`.

5.exit terminal and restart terminal(DO NOT NEED TO Restart Mac), input

the below on terminal

```
vim --version | grep "python3"
```

checkout whether the symbol bdfore "python3" is `+` or Not?

"`+`" means `VIM` support `python3`, but "`-`" Not.

____________________________________________________________---Way 0 END---:)

____________________________________________________---Way 1 Start---(::

Way 1:

First, you need to use this to checkout whether `VIM` support `Python3` or not?

```
vim --version | grep python
```

you may see the terminal output liking:

```
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +visual
```

as the upstairs shows: that Mac default installed `VIM` DO NOT SUPPORT `Python3`.

And that default installed `VIM` of Mac is not been installed via "`brew`".

Now, we could not use liking "`brew remove`" to delate that default installed `VIM` of Mac,

and it's also why your action

```
"brew delete vim and brew cleanup and reinstalled Vim"
```

DO NOT FUNCTION!

Second,

we need to know where that fu-king default installed `VIM` with not supporting `python3`,

```
which vim
```

output:

```
/usr/bin/vim
```

mostly shows like the upstairs(depends default macOS).

Even we use "`--with-python3` " to install `VIM` with supporting

`Python3`at a long time, but Now `Homebrew` ONLY recognize "`python -V`"'s version.

SO we NEED to manually let default `python` to be `python3`.

Open your terminal and input:

```
alias python="python3"
```

then checkout `python` that that version whether is `python3` or not:

```
python -V
```

then, we found that "`python -V`" shows "`Python 3.9.12`".

Third,

That's time to use `Homebrew` to install `VIM`.

```
brew install vim
```

After installing Homebrew`VIM`, we need to make sure where is Homebrew`VIM`,

differ from that default installed `VIM` of Mac:

```
which vim
```

output:

```
/usr/local/bin/vim
```

(Also, `DO` `NOT` `NEED` `TO` `restart Your Mac`), Just restart Your Terminal(then you will reenter your terminal)!!!

then, we need to checkout whether that Homebrew`VIM` supports `Python3` or Not:

```
vim --version | grep python
```

output:

```
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +visual
```

Successful!

__________________________________________________---Way 1 Terminal---::)

END!

Comment: Thanks!

Weirdly, I didn't have to restart my Mac, but after terminal restart everything worked (also needed to cleanup a back vimrc file). I skipped the shell tweak and haven't had any issues yet, but then again, I had only been using the Mac default vim and didn't need to uninstall a homebrew installed one.

Comment: @dandam, thank you for your feedback! Have a nice day!